# Google App Maker will soon be deprecated. What alternative will App Maker experts like Markus Malessa move to?

Tags: google-app-maker

Markus Malessa has provided some fantastic answers to Goole App Maker questions here on Stack Overflow. However, App Maker will soon be decommissioned. What will be the preferred alternative for App Maker experts like Markus?

Comment: PowerApps = less code or no code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appreciate the call out although I would not necessarily consider myself an ‘expert’ by any means. I do have to say that the initial choice for AM was largely due to the fact that it was part of our G Suite subscription and I was somewhat familiar with Google Apps Script and HTML/CSS due to some free standing app development using the HtmlService. Given that my background and education is actually not programming related at all I would consider myself to be the target market for these types of programs were little to no code is required.

Unfortunately the reality is that my place of work never really committed much funding to this project outside of my time and more so this was probably what some coders would apparently refer to as their 20% project. So really at the moment I am not sure yet where I will end up after this. I’m afraid though that unless we decide to pony up some funds for something else we will be back where we used to be before this without a lot of functionality.

Anyway best of luck to all citizen developers that took a plunge into App Maker, you guys are all great and it has been a pleasure providing feedback to you all.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Angular, since it's also based on JavaScript.